# finding Laurent series intervals

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find all the Laurent series for the below function around z=0.

> f(z) = 3/(2+z-z^2)

I think the intervals are:

1: 0 < |z| < 1 
2: 1 < |z| < 2  
3: |z| > 2

Is that correct?

Comment: My question is that are these 3 intervals the correct intervals on which I have to find the Laurent series for the function?

Comment: The sets are *not* intervals. Each of them is an annulus. Other than that, you are right.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos Right, Thanks for your help.